# El documento se corrompe al agregar imágenes en PhpWord

Tags: php, phpword

Estoy trabajando con la biblioteca PHPWord de PHPOffice con plantillas y estoy teniendo un problema.

El detalle ocurre al generar un documento Word. Todo bien al hacer los reemplazos de texto, pero cuando quiero agregar imágenes (con el método `setImageValue()`) el documento generado no puede abrirse.

He buscado la forma de habilitar la depuración, pero no puedo encontrarla. También tengo la sospecha de que el error puede ser generado por las dimensiones y peso de las imágenes, pero ya intenté modificando con `width`, `height` y `ratio`.

Les comparto mi código:

```php
<?php

require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/assets/php/phpoffice/phpword/vendor/autoload.php";

$filename = "Historia_Clinica_$whapp.docx";
header('Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');

$templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor("templates/Historia_Clinica.docx");

$templateProcessor->setValue("fechaExpediente", $respuesta_fecha_expediente);
$templateProcessor->setValue("nombre",          $respuesta_nombre);
$templateProcessor->setValue("motivo",          $respuesta_motivo);
$templateProcessor->setValue("enfermedades",    $respuesta_enfermedades);
$templateProcessor->setValue("alergias",        $respuesta_alergias);
$templateProcessor->setValue("medicamentos",    $respuesta_medicamentos);
$templateProcessor->setValue("edad",            $respuesta_edad);
$templateProcessor->setValue("fechaNacimiento", $respuesta_fecha_nacimiento);
$templateProcessor->setValue("estadoCivil",     $respuesta_estado_civil);
$templateProcessor->setValue("ocupacion",       $respuesta_ocupacion);
$templateProcessor->setValue("direccion",       $respuesta_direccion);
$templateProcessor->setValue("celular",         $whapp);
$templateProcessor->setValue("recomendado",     $respuesta_recomendado);

$select = $con->select("chats_mensajes", "Id_Chat_Mensaje");
$select->innerjoin("chats USING(Id_Chat)");
$select->where("Whapp", "=", $whapp);
$select->where_and("Mensaje", "=", "IMAGE");

$selection = $select->execute();

foreach ($selection as $x => $image) {
    if ($x > 7) {
        $x = 7;

        break;
    }

    $id_chat_mensaje = $image["Id_Chat_Mensaje"];

    // $templateProcessor->setValue("imagen$x", "img/messages/$id_chat_mensaje.jpg"); #Con esta línea confirme que mis documentos si estaban siendo generados y que las rutas eran correctas.
    $templateProcessor->setImageValue("imagen$x", "img/messages/$id_chat_mensaje.jpg");
}

if ($x == count($selection) - 1 && $x < 7) {
    for ($i = $x + 1; $i < 8; $i++) {
        $templateProcessor->setValue("imagen$i", "");
    }
}

$templateProcessor->saveAs("php://output");

?>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir en algún sitio el archivo corrupto que te ha generado? Puede ser mega, onedrive, github, etc.

Comment: Claro, este es el archivo generado:https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xB3QaM7wmcDfbll36dPVZrkxPJoxgllF/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=102469134971002990894&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: He usado `xmllint` para comprobar los archivos XML y el archivo `document.xml` presenta gran número de errores en el espacio de nombres del elemento `imagedata`. Voy a depurar un poco más el problema para ver si es culpa de la biblioteca de funciones, la plantilla o cualquier otro origen.

Comment: Arreglado. El problema está en tu plantilla. ¿Podrías compartirla? Le falta la definición de los espacios de nombres `v` y `o`. Una vez que arreglas ese problema el documento se genera de manera satisfactoria. Te comparto el documento correctamente generado para que lo compares con el tuyo: https://1drv.ms/w/s!AlkRojGYyKEpiWx6oDcfRnhmBf8M?e=dNipZN

Comment: Excelente, esta mi plantilla: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1KVRXeyKKCVA3kn6RW2r9xUWzNqFQb8tG/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=109887585166452750993&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Estoy viendo en la plantilla que, además de los espacios de nombres que faltan, las macros están divididos en diferentes elementos `<w:t>`, por lo que es posible que se pueda romper también el formato XML del documento.

Comment: Tengo que salir y no vuelvo hasta dentro de unas 3 horas. Con lo que he puesto en los comentarios espero que alguien pueda ayudarte a corregir la plantilla. En caso contrario cuando vuelva lo hago yo. Suerte!

Comment: Muchas gracias, de momento veré que puedo hacer.

Comment: He redactado una respuesta explicándote el problema con el documento de plantilla y una manera sencilla de corregirlo. He de decirte que, en realidad, esto es un error de la biblioteca de funciones `\PhpOffice\PhpWord`. Tú tendrías que despreocuparte de los detalles técnicos de la estructura del documento DOCX con el que trabajas. Sería interesante reportar este mal funcionamiento que para lo corrijan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El documento de la plantilla no tiene definidos los siguientes dos espacios de nombres (`xmlns`) en el archivo `word/document.xml`:

- xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
- xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"

Cuando insertas las imágenes hacen uso de ellos como puedes ver a continuación (he usado `xmllint --format word/document.xml` para poder ver el XML con mejor formato):

```
<w:pict>
  <v:shape type="#_x0000_t75" style="width:39.375px;height:70px" stroked="f">
    <v:imagedata r:id="rId8" o:title=""/>
  </v:shape>
</w:pict>
```

Donde comprobar ver que tanto `<v:shape>` como `<v:imagedata>` usan el espacio de nombres `v`. El atributo `o:title` de este último usa el espacio de nombres `o`.

Sin embargo, el documento solo tiene estos espacios de nombres definidos:

```
<w:document
    xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
    xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"
>...</w:document>
```

Para agregarlos puedes realizar las siguientes acciones:

```
# Extraemos el contenido del documento
unzip Historia_Clinica.docx
# Agregamos los espacios de nombres en el archivo XML
xmlstarlet edit -L \
    --insert "/w:document" --type attr \
    -n "xmlns:o" -v "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" \
    --insert "/w:document" --type attr \
    -n "xmlns:v" -v "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" \
    word/document.xml
# Volvemos a crear el documento corregido
zip -r Historia_Clinica_Corregido.docx . -x "*.docx"
```

Tienes el documento de plantilla corregido disponible en el siguiente enlace:

- [Historia_Clinica_Corregido.docx](https://1drv.ms/w/s!AlkRojGYyKEpiW-Xkxm4ucqAZJrm?e=dHX5X8)

Si inspeccionas el archivo corregido verás que ahora los espacios de nombres son los correctos:

```xml
<w:document
    xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
    xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
    xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
>
```

Comment: Sí era eso, estaba trabajando con otro editor para generar el documento plantilla, no pensé que se fuera a dañar el formato perdiendo esas definiciones, nunca lo hubiera notado de no ser por tu ayuda, muchas gracias.